# How to display alert box(Javascript) using OpenWebkitSharp(C#)?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, open-webkit-sharp

As per title, any method to allow alert message from HTML to be displayed in OpenWebkitSharp  (C#)?

Scenario

1. Browsing HTML using OpenWebkitSharp webbrowser program(C#).
2. Clicking a button in HTML.
3. button onclick: alert('show message');.

P.S: I'm using OpenWebkitSharp version 2.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
WebKitBrowser webKitSharpBrowser = new WebKitBrowser();
webKitSharpBrowser.UseJavaScript = true;
```

Comment: "webKitBrowser1.UseJavaScript = true;" I have checked the API, this statement is true by default :) But still can't display the alert box. Your tried already can?

Answer (score -2):

U need implements that methods.

```
        webKitBrowser.ShowJavaScriptAlertPanel += new ShowJavaScriptAlertPanelEventHandler(delegate(object o, ShowJavaScriptAlertPanelEventArgs e) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        });
        webKitBrowser.ShowJavaScriptConfirmPanel += new ShowJavaScriptConfirmPanelEventHandler(delegate(object o, ShowJavaScriptConfirmPanelEventArgs e) {
            e.ReturnValue = MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK;
        });
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).